How many built-in microphones does an iPhone actually have?
For example on iPhone 7, there's a "hole" at the bottom, at the top and at the back where the Camera is located.
Teardowns show 3 mics, but is it really 3 microphones that software can tap?
I was trying to re-create Wo MIC and EZ Mic. And I was trying to list up available Microphones and ended up just getting one as a result.
However, when I tell the iPhone to use a different data source, then it will use it.
So I am wondering, do these "holes" count as a separate mic, or is it all just one Microphone?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are you interested in physical components which register sound, or in number of internal microphones addressable by software (or the user)?
